# SSIS - Fixed number of columns in flat file source

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a number of text files in a directory which have a set number of columns [6] separated by tabs. I read this into an SSIS package using a 'Flat File Source' block. If a file has more columns than the required number or if data is missing from any of the columns, I want to reject this file.

I have done some testing with various sample files. Whenever I add additional columns, the program accepts these files. It throws an error when there are less columns which is good.

But, is there a way of specifying that the file must have a certain amount of columns and that data must be present in each column?

I don't have much experience with SSIS so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would use a Script Task to do this.

You can use `System.IO.StreamReader` to open the file and read your header row, and then perform whatever validation you need on the resulting string.

I would also create a Boolean variable in the SSIS package, called something like 'FileIsValid', to which I would write (from the Script Task) True if the conditions are met, and False if they aren't. I would then use this to direct the package flow using precedence constraints.

Something like this:

```
public void Main()
{
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::FileIsValid"].Value = false;

        reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Dts.Variables["User::Filepath"].Value.ToString());

        string header = reader.ReadLine();

        if (header.Trim() == "Column1\tColumn2\tColumn3\tColumn4\tColumn5\tColumn6")
            Dts.Variables["User::FileIsValid"].Value = true;

        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

With regards to checking there is data in all columns, does this need to be for every row?

You could continue reading the lines with `StreamReader` and use regular expressions to check for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Chris Mack:

If files do not have headers you can do a count.

```
char[] delim = new char[] {'\t'};
if(header.Split(delim).Length() == 5)
...
```